# PostgreSQL JsonB can't use IN operator on numbers

Tags: json, postgresql, nosql, jsonb

I have a table with 4 columns and the following types.

```
|id          |businessId|type       |data |
|VARCHAR(100)|BIGINT    |VARCHAR(50)|jsonb|
```

My query needs to get all items with type 'XXX' and field from the *data* **depID** having one of the values 1 2 or 3.

This is how my query looks at the moment

```
select * from test_table where type='XXX' and data ->> 'depID' IN (1, 2, 3);
```

The above query give the following error:

```
[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: text = integer Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

*depID* is of type number in the json.

Same query works just fine for string values, for example:

```
select * from test_table where type='XXX' and data ->> 'loc' IN ('NYC', 'BST', 'None');
```

*loc* is of string type in the json.

I understand that it cant figure that the *depID* is of type number, but I am not sure how to specify it.

How to specify that the type of *depID* is number?

**EDIT**:

It turns out I was reading old specifications. I am using *Postgres 11.4*

The correct syntax is the following.

```
select * from test_table where type='XXX' and (data->>'depID'):NUMERIC IN (1, 2, 3);
```

The *->>* operator has returns string. This explains why string fields work without casting.

Comment: How to specify that the type of depID is number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `->>` operator has `text` as result data type, so it cannot return a number.

It would be possible to add a special access operator for numbers, but that would just clutter the ooerator namespace needlessly, since it can be done with a simple type cast:

```
CAST (data ->> 'depID' AS integer) IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: you are right, the default data type is string. Your solutions works. What is the difference between CAST(.. AS integer) and (..)::NUMERIC. ?

Comment: `::` is PostgreSQL's shortcut for `CAST`, so no difference there. If the numbers are not necessarily integers, use `numeric` by all means.